# Problem with code 0 error when using FastAPI via ajax in javascript

Tags: ajax, async-await, request, fastapi

In order to connect with FastAPI through ajax in javascript, html was written as follows.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
        <input type="button" onclick="search(1, 2)" style="width:30px;"/>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var search = function(a,b){
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
                data : {start: a, end: b},
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                accept: "application/json",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("code:"+XMLHttpRequest.status);
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And next, it was written as follows to respond in a post method using FastAPI.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Request, Path


app = FastAPI()



@app.post('/')
async def receiveLocationInfo(request: Request):
    result = await request.body()

return result
```

However, code 0 was returned as an error, not success, was performed in Ajax. What is the problem?
Please note that it might be awkward because I am not good at English

Answer (score 0):

you need to set corse origin into your app

```
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
ORIGINS = ['*']
app.add_middleware(
            CORSMiddleware,
            allow_origins=ORIGINS,
            allow_credentials=True,
            allow_methods=["*"],
            allow_headers=["*"],
        )
```